# Can't Create Item When Table Has Data

Tags: content-management-system, directus

I have a problem where if my table is empty, I can create new items with Directus. But, if the table has data already I get the error ID: Value has to be unique. I'm using auto increment for my ID's. Any ideas what I've done wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had similar issue after importing data from another directus and database. I was able to resolve this issue by going into postgres database using psql and resetting auto increment with `SELECT setval('my_table_id_seq', (SELECT max(id) FROM my_table));` and then inserting one row `INSERT INTO my_table(column1, column2, ...) VALUES (value1, value2, ...);` after that I was able to create new table rows thru directs.

Answer (score 0):

You can also just keep pressing "Save" and keep getting the error until the sequence gets to the next available value, just did it and it worked. :laugh: